# I can not open my emulator in android studio that i have created

Tags: android-studio, emulation, virtual-device-manager

I can not open my emulator in android studio that i have created. i install lollipop platform in SDK and create same api level emulator. see the error log in bellow image. i have set 512 ram for virtual device.

error log[image]

error log details[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Generally, we try to put the entire text into the submission so that the question stands on its own, even if that external site goes down.  If you copy/paste your log as text then place four spaces in front of each line to denote that section as code, you will likely get a better response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android emulator requires the Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX). Ensure WHPX is properly installed and usable.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/